# elixir: why two boolean operators for the same operation

Tags: elixir

Elixir seems to have 2 boolean operators for each operation:

```
|| , or
&& , and
```

etc. The only difference is that for `or, and` etc, the first argument itself has to be a boolean. What is the point of these second set of operators, when `|| , &&` etc seem to be able to handle everything?

Comment: did you read the question? I asked for an example of what or/and can do that ||/&& can't. Do you see an example for that in the tutorial?

Comment: The phrase "_or_ and _and_ are short-circuit operators. They only execute the right side if the left side is not enough to determine the result." seems to answer pretty clearly why there are two sets of operators to me. It seems that you just didn't bother to look before you asked. One reason for downvote is "this question doesn't show any research effort"--I'd say that describes this quite well.

Comment: what do you think will be the output here `true || raise("error")`?

Comment: Since || is going to return true if the left side of the expression is "truthy" I expect it to return true and never raise an error.  And a quick check in iex shows me I'm right.  Look, I could have just downvoted your question without bothering to say why I did.  I thought I was being a little bit courteous to spell out why I considered the question as being something to downvote rather than just downvoting without comment.  Try not to get so defensive.

Comment: so `||` also seems to 'short-circuit'? I still don't see how it's different from `or`.

Comment: `Or` takes two boolean parameters.  `||` takes two parameters of any type as @ham-sandwich put in his or her answer. Use `or` if you're expecting booleans `||` otherwise.

Comment: so you agree that `short-circuit` is not an advantage of `or`? If so, what's the motivation for having an operator that can only handle booleans, when there's another that can handle data of any type?

Comment: Take a look at the answer I just posted @tldr.

Answer (score 12):

According to the Elixir Tutorials on [Basic Operators](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-operators.html):

> `or` and `and` are short-circuit operators. They only execute the right
>   side if the left side is not enough to determine the result

To answer your question, *what is the point of the second set of operators?*; I think the tutorial puts it quite nicely.

> As a rule of thumb, use `and`, `or` and `not` when you are expecting
>   booleans. If any of the arguments are non-boolean, use `&&`, `||` and `!`.

**My Take**

1. To me it seems to be *best practice* within the language itself.
2. Inline with the *let it fail* philosophy, being more strict with types could be a good idea in comparison situations.In **iex(5)** the result throws an ArgumentError. Throwing such an error may be a better idea than wrongly evaluating something.

**`&&` and `and` Example**

```
iex(1)> nil && 13
nil

iex(2)> true && 17
17

iex(3)> true and true
true

iex(4)> false and true
false

iex(5)> 73 and false
** (ArgumentError) argument error: 73
```

Comment: thanks for writing this out. i am a bit confused by the documentation you listed. what does "use `and`, `or` and `not` when you are expecting booleans." does this mean the evaluation will return a boolean? 
in this example: 
```iex(1)> 56 && true
true
iex(2)> true && 56
56
iex(3)> true and 56
56
iex(4)> 56 and true
** (BadBooleanError) expected a boolean on left-side of "and", got: 56```
iex(1) returns `true` when i'd expect `56` since i am using `&&`. iex(3) returns `56` when i'd expect `true` since i am using `and`

Comment: Hey. It's the same kind of story in Perl. `true && true` => `true`, whereas the 'short-circuit' is more for after-the-fact operations. `true and do_this_function()`.  Where if `true` was `false` in the above, then `do_this_function()` would never be executed. You want to use the words if you want something to happen based on the condition of the first.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, straight from the source of truth for all things Elixir:

> Two main reasons:
>
> 1. Writing assertive code: if you are expecting a boolean, use a boolean
> 2. Guards are strictly booleans, so you have to use "and" and "or" in there

That's straight from Jose Valim.

Also Peter Hamilton (credit where credit's due) pointed out this enlightening message from Robert Virding, one of the creators of Erlang:

> A little bit of history and some philosophy about boolean operators
>   and guards.
>
> Long-ago we explicitly decided to have boolean operators 'and', 'or',
>   'xor' and 'not' and not have truthy values. This was not because we
>   weren't familiar with truthy logic, which we were being long-time C
>   and lisp programmers, we just felt it was more logical (haha). These
>   were originally all strict and only accepted boolean arguments. Later
>   there came a desire for short-circuiting 'and' and 'or'. Instead of
>   redefining 'and' and 'or' we added the new operators 'andalso' and
>   'orelse'. Originally these were andalso(bool,bool) and
>   orelse(bool,bool) and would thus test the value of the second
>   argument. This is later changed so that the second argument was not
>   checked, for amongst other reasons that this is how it is in other
>   languages and because of the possibility for tail-call optimisation. I
>   have personally never had use of that.
>
> I am personally not a fan of truthy operators and think 'nil' smells a
>   bit like null in other languages.
>
> About guards. Originally they were guard *tests* and considered an
>   extension of the pattern matching with things that couldn't nicely be
>   written as a pattern. A test either succeeded or failed. IMAO this
>   made guards more consistent wrt content and handling
>   failure/exceptions, which was just a failed test. When the allowed
>   guards became complex they wandered to becoming guard expressions
>   which return boolean values and then the guard as a whole became a
>   boolean expression. This, I think, made it more difficult to explain
>   why guards look and behave like they do.

I am marking this answer as community wiki because it's not really my answer per se.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to me that wanting to have a boolean value as first argument can be helpful when you dont want to interpret any other value(or datatype) as true, as elixir will take anything for true except for nil and false. User may want to make sure that the argument is a boolean (either true or false) and not accidently except any other type of value.

Boolean operators like *or*, *and*, *not* expect true or false as their first argument

Relaxed boolean operators like *||*, *&&*, *!* can take arguments of any type. Any value other than nil or false is interpreted as true(truthy).

For example

```
x || y # gives x if x is truthy else y
x && y # gives y if x is truthy else x
!x # false if x is truthy , otherwise true
```

If you try

```
iex(5)> not 3     
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.not(3)

iex(6)> ! 3
false
```

Comment: does this apply to similarly formatted programming languages, such as Python, or C?

Comment: @JosephFarah sorry dont have much idea of other languages